# How to generate any random time ranging from 24 hours ago until current system time?

Tags: java

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
```

How or where do I proceed from this line of code?

Comment: @DmitriiB - Your solution is spot on. Why don't you post it as an answer? A comment may be deleted.

Comment: @Live and Let Live Ok, I do it :-)

Answer (score 7):

you can do it:

```
LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(new Random().nextInt(24));
```

if you need you similarly can add `.minusMinutes(new Random().nextInt(60))` or `.minusSeconds(new Random().nextInt(60))`

Answer (score 2):

This function gives you a `LocalDateTime` within the last 24 hours. The random value is been taken based on the seconds of 24 hours:

```java
import java.time.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public LocalDateTime randomLast24Hours() {
  Long secondsOfDay = Duration.ofDays(1).getSeconds();
  Long randomSeconds = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(secondsOfDay + 1);
  return LocalDateTime.now().minusSeconds(randomSeconds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I just saw that ChristianB posted a more random solution but im just gonna leave this here in case someone needs just random hours.

```
public static LocalDateTime minusRandomHours(int inputHours) {
    int hours = new Random().nextInt(inputHours);
    LocalDateTime randomTime = LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(hours);
    return randomTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to code something more customizable or return especific info from a time you can use the Java Calendar Class, for example:

```
import java.util.Caldenar;

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour_now = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // returns the hour now as integer
```

Also, by using the `LocalDate.of()` and the `getDayOfWeek().name()` function is possible to get the name of the day. For example:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

String name_day = LocalDate.of(2021, 01, 10).getDayOfWeek().name();
```

My code outputs the random time like this:

[image]

Check it out....

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;

public class randLast24Hours {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Random rand = new Random();
int rand_hour;
int rand_minutes;
int today = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // get today's day of the month
int hour_now = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // hour now
int minutes_now = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE); // minutes now
int rand_day = rand.nextInt(2) + today - 1; // rand between yesterday & today
String name_day = LocalDate.of(2021, 01, rand_day).getDayOfWeek().name();
int rand_hour_yesterday = rand.nextInt(23-hour_now) + hour_now;
int rand_hour_today = rand.nextInt(hour_now+1);

// choose rand_hour and rand_minutes depending on what's the rand_day
if(rand_day == today){rand_hour = rand_hour_today;
rand_minutes = rand.nextInt(minutes_now);}

else {rand_hour = rand_hour_yesterday;
rand_minutes = rand.nextInt(60);}

int rand_seconds = rand.nextInt(60);

System.out.println("Random time for the last 24hrs:");
System.out.print(name_day+" ");if(rand_hour < 10) {System.out.print("0");}
System.out.print(rand_hour+":");if(rand_minutes < 10) {System.out.print("0");}
System.out.print(rand_minutes+":");if(rand_seconds < 10) {System.out.print("0");}
System.out.print(rand_seconds);}}
```