# How can randomize a time between yesterday and today's local DateTime in java?

Tags: java, random, localdatetime

I need to randomize a time in java.

If now the time is `24/2/2021 13:56:13`, then I need to randomize a time between `23/2/2021 13:56:13` and `24/2/2021 13:56:13`. I am not familiar to random function in Java so that I maybe need some help. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: E.g. take the end time, subtract the start time, take the number of seconds of that duration, take a random number between 0 and that number and add it onto the start time.

Comment: You can also check [this similar Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65619315/how-to-generate-any-random-time-ranging-from-24-hours-ago-until-current-system-t/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate any random time ranging from 24 hours ago until current system time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65619315/how-to-generate-any-random-time-ranging-from-24-hours-ago-until-current-system-t)

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 3):

Take `LocalDateTime.now()` then go back in time with a random amount of seconds between 0 and 86400

```
int randomSeconds = new Random().nextInt(3600 * 24);
LocalDateTime anyTime = LocalDateTime.now().minusSeconds(randomSeconds);
System.out.println(anyTime);
```

---

**General solution**

1. Define the beginning `dates` and end of the period
2. Compute the difference in seconds and get a random int in that range
3. Compute the random date with one of these 2 ways:

   - Go from the beginning and add the random amount of seconds
   - Go from the end and remove the random amount of seconds

```
LocalDateTime periodStart = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1);
LocalDateTime periodEnd = LocalDateTime.now();

int randomSeconds = new Random().nextInt((int) periodStart.until(periodEnd, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));

//LocalDateTime anyTime = periodStart.plusSeconds(randomSeconds);
LocalDateTime anyTime = periodEnd.minusSeconds(randomSeconds);
```

Comment: This might lead to incorrect results around the start and end of Daylight Saving Time (DST).